# Adding mouseout delay effect in a gallery thumbnail

Tags: jquery, html, css

On [this](http://www.modoluce.com/#/collezioni) webpage, there is a thumbnail mouseover effect i like.
Is this effect possible with CSS3 or jQuery?
I searched a lot to find this effect, but I can't find one.
Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: you can use css3 transition http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 0):

This effect is done with two images and JavaScript.
They added both images over each other and just trigger the `display`. This makes a very bad hover effect, when you hover the elements very fast.

So for this effect, CSS3 is much better! Just add a background-image to the link, add a background-image-transition to the link and change the background-image when hovering the element.

[Here is a working CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxfLi)

To change the duration of the effect or the animation-type, take a look to [this](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/#.Um4VCPnIt8E) page, which tells you all the different animation-types.

---

**Edit**
To have a longer duration of the transition when you hover the mouse out than when you hover the mouse on, just add an additional `transition` statement.
[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzGCo) is again a working Codepen Demo with a *0.3s* on-hover duration and a *1s* hover out duration.

```
a{
   /* This is the transition, when you hover OUT the element */
   transition: background 1s;
}

a:hover{
   /* This is the transition, when you hover ON the element */
   transition: background 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.already i know this method with css3 transition. it is fine.but i want to make more slow on mouse out when it comparing to mouse over.then only get that effect what i think.

Comment: @vipin: Please take a look to my edited answer. I added a solution to have two different durations of the transition. Is it what you mean?